# maven plugin - get artifactId of plugin in Mojo

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is it possible to get the artifactId of the current Mojo?

```
@Mojo(...)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    @Parameter(property = "project")
    private MavenProject project;
    @Parameter(property = "inputDirectory", defaultValue = "${project.basedir}/src/main/${artifact id of the plugin}")
    private File inputDirectory;

   ...
```

I could hardcode the artifact id of the plugin, but I would rather get it dynamically.

Comment: Why do you need the artifactId of the mojo? What is the purpose?

Comment: We have a lot of plugins to maintain. Since we are still in development phase, they tend to change a lot. Some plugins require input sources (see example). I would like to have these sources in a directory with the same name as the artifact identifier, to keep things aligned and structured.

Comment: First i would use `${project.build.sourceDirectory}` instead of `${project.basedir}`. Why do you need to maintain many plugins? What are the problems? Sounds to me that you doing things wrong? Apart from that naming the folder based on the artifactid of the plugins Hm...better name based on the idea of the source like `src/main/groovy`, `src/main/cpp` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

BTW what comes into my mind is that you are using old style injection

```java
@Parameter(property = "project")
private MavenProject project;

@Parameter(property = "inputDirectory", defaultValue = "${project.basedir}/src/main/${artifact id of the plugin}")
private File inputDirectory;
```

[They should look like this:](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html)

The expression values for defaultValue are documented here: 
http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html depending on your used Maven version.

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}, required = true, readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project.basedir}/src/main/${artifact id of the plugin}", property = "inputDirectory", required = true)
private File inputDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not answer the question.

You can use a field to dynamically get the artifactId of the mojo (not the artifactId of the project which the plugin is attached on)

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${mojo.artifactId}")
private String mojoArtifactId;
```

Or in your case:

```java
@Parameter(property = "project")
private MavenProject project;

@Parameter(property = "inputDirectory", defaultValue = "${project.basedir}/src/main/${mojo.artifactId}")
private File inputDirectory;
```